# How can one see fields in a subclass of java.util.HashMap in the debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a subclass of HashMap in our code with some other features and it exhibits one of our interfaces.

There are a few protected fields in this object with accessors XX getXX() setXX(XX value).

When I look at an instance of this object in the Intellij version of the java debugger ( java 8.1 ) it does not show the fields in the subclass, yet it does show me the tuples in the map itself.

Is this a bug ? am I doing something wrong ?
If create a new instance of the map and assign it to a handle in the former subclass and put wrappers for all the interface methods that now have to access the map indirectly the debugger DOES show the fields in the object.

This seems odd.

Thanks.

Comment: How does it look like, can you show screenshots? Have you tried to cast the object to subclass?

Comment: Have you have customized any [Java Type Renderers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugger-data-type-renderers.html)?

Comment: Nope I don't have customized debug renderers unless they are part of the stock intellij install.  Casts have no effect it does know the class and display that and it's "address" properly.   I do have one custom type renderer for "char" to show it both as a character and in hex.  That's it.

Comment: I could put a breakpoint inside a method of the object and even "this" does not show the object's fields.  Simple to reproduce, make an object that subclasses HashMap or LinkedHashMap and put a couple of fields in it.

Answer (score 1):

For the standard java collections (and their inheritors) IDEA debugger shows their elements instead of fields.
You can change this behavior:

- from the object context menu using View as - Object
- disabling rendering collections in the settings (Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java - Enable alternative view for Collection classes)

If you want to see both collection elements and fields, you can create a custom renderer like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks - doesn't help much as one really wants to see BOTH our added fields and the map view. ( which can be expanded or collapsed )  but I guess toggling though uses more click and select operations does allow this.

Comment: I updated the answer, to see both - use a custom renderer